# lvm: metadata demon deprecated, unavailable in 20.04 and higher?

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, lvm

The Logical Volume Manager (lvm) metadata daemon seems to be available (and recommended to be in a running state) in Ubuntu up to version 18.04 LTS, but for 20.04 it is not even available

`sudo systemctl status lvm<tab>` does not list it.

on 20.04:

```
$ sudo systemctl status lvm2

lvm2-activation-early.service  lvm2-monitor.service
lvm2-activation.service        lvm2-pvscan@8:3.service
lvm2-lvmpolld.service          lvm2.service
lvm2-lvmpolld.socket
```

but on 18.04:

```
lvm2-activation.service   lvm2-lvmpolld.service     lvm2-pvscan@8:16.service
====================
lvm2-lvmetad.service      lvm2-lvmpolld.socket      lvm2-pvscan@8:5.service
lvm2-lvmetad.socket       lvm2-monitor.service      lvm2.service
===================
```

(highlighted by me)

Why? is this documented somewhere?

I can find a [forum post](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/62289) on the ArchLinux Wiki, but I'd like to find something more "official". Has `lvm2.metad` been replaced with something? Or merged?

In Ubuntu 18.84, there is some documentation [available](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man8/lvmetad.8.html) on the LVM metadata daemon, but for 20.04 and higher it is not. An equivalent manually-crafted [link to 20.04](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man8/lvmetad.8.html) currently redirectly to 18.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lvm2.metad was deprecated and finally removed in version 2.03.00:
https://github.com/lvmteam/lvm2/blob/master/WHATS_NEW

Ubuntu removed it with version lvm2 (2.03.01-1):
https://launchpad.net/debian/+source/lvm2/+changelog